# Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\SourceItemsProcessor does not exis

Tags: magento2.3.4

I have problem with command php bin/magento setup:di:compile

in round 5 the command stop work and i get this error

Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [==========>---]  71% 40 secs 271.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 43:

Class Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\SourceItemsProcessor does not exist

In ClassReader.php line 36:

Class Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\SourceItemsProcessor does not exist